# How to determine which method of OCR to use depending on images quality

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr

I am asking a question, because my two week research are started to get me really confused.

I have a bunch of images, from which I want to get the numbers in Runtime (it is needed for reward function in Reinforcment Learning). The thing is, that they are pretty clear for me (I know that it is absolutely different thing for OCR-systems, but that's why I am providing additional images to show what I am talking about)

[image]
[image]
[image]

And I thought that because they are rather clear. So I've tried to use PyTesseract and when it does not worked out I have tried to research which other methods could be useful to me.

... and that's how my search ended here, because two weeks of trying to find out which method would be bestly suited for my problem just raised more questions.

Currently I think that the best resolve for it is to create digit recognizing model from MNIST/SVNH dataset, but is not it a little bit overkill? I mean, images are standardized, they are in Grayscale, they are small, and the numbers font stays the same so I suppose that there is easier way of modyfing those images/using different OCR method.

That is why I am asking for two questions:

1. Which method should be the most useful for my case, if not model
   trained with MNIST/SVNH datasets?
2. Is there any kind of documentation/books/sources which could make the actual choice of infrastructure easier? I mean, let's say
   that in future I will come up again to plan which OCR system to use.
   On what basis should I make choice? Is it purely trial and error
   thing?

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow IMO.

Comment: Is it? Should I post such a question on other Stack-like site?

Comment: It is indeed, see: [help/on-topic]. The first question is not a specific programming problem, the second one is explicitly off-topic. Try the Statistics Stack Exchange? There might be a ML/OCR-specific one, I’m not sure.

Comment: Sure! Sorry for that. I thought that I could post a questions related to programming there too, without code-specific question.

Comment: Check out [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you have to recognize are those 7 segment digits, forget about any OCR package.

Use the outline of the window to find the size and position of the digits. Then count the black pixels in seven predefined areas, facing the segments.

[image]

Comment: I would never guess such a resolution for this problem, really. Thank you!